# Django Подскажите как настроить вариацию товаров

Tags: python, django

Подскажите как сделать чтобы можно было отдельно добавить возможность выбора Вариации из Tag и после выбрать нужные Variety в Product

```
#*******************************
#*******************************
#model.py
#*******************************
#*******************************

class Variety(models.Model):

varietyName = models.CharField(max_length=30)

def __str__(self):
return self.varietyName

class Meta:
verbose_name = "Список вариации"
verbose_name_plural = "Список вариаций"

class Tag(models.Model):

STATUS_VARIETY=(
('Filters', 'ФИЛЬТР'),
('Variaty', 'Вариация'),
('Boths', 'Оба'),
)
status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_VARIETY, default='Boths', verbose_name='Статус')
name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Название')
variety = models.ManyToManyField(Variety, related_name='children', verbose_name='Родитель')

def __str__(self):
return self.name

class Meta:
verbose_name = "Вариация"
verbose_name_plural = "Вариации"

class Productcopy(models.Model):

STATUS_PRODUCT=(
('Publish', 'Опубликовать'),
('Not_to_publish', 'Не публиковать'),
)

status = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=STATUS_PRODUCT, verbose_name='Статус')
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Название')
tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, verbose_name='Вариация', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
variety = models.ManyToManyField(Variety, verbose_name='вариации')

def __str__(self):
return self.name

class Meta:
verbose_name = "товары"
verbose_name_plural = "товары"

#*******************************
#*******************************
#admin.py
#*******************************
#*******************************

from django.contrib import admin

from .models import *

class TagAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ('name', 'status',)
filter_horizontal = ('variety',)

class ProductcopyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ('name', 'status',)
filter_horizontal = ('variety',)

admin.site.register(Tag,TagAdmin)
admin.site.register(Productcopy,ProductcopyAdmin)
admin.site.register(Variety)
```

[image: Здесь все описано]

Comment: `tag.variety_set.prefetch_related()`

Comment: Извиняюсь за глупый вопрос. Как именно и куда его разместить? Я только только начал изучать Django

Comment: Зависит от того, где именно вам это нужно. Если просто итерируетесь по Tag Queryset, то  `tag.variety_set.prefetch_related()`

Comment: мне нужно чтобы в админке была возможность выбрать вариацию.  как с вами связаться чтобы показать код и данные с базы? исправил описание и добавил фото

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы именно в режиме реально времени выбирать `tag` и получать обновленный список для выбора - стандартными средствами админки это невозможно. Можно сделать так: выбираете `tag`, сохраняете, и потом уже верный список для выбора будет доступным. В целом, как-то так:

```
class ProductcopyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'status',)
    filter_horizontal = ('variety',)

    def get_object(self, request, object_id, from_field=None):
        obj = super().get_object(request, object_id, from_field=from_field)
        request.product_obj = obj
        return obj

    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "variety" and hasattr(request, 'product_obj'):
            kwargs["queryset"] = request.product_obj.tag.variety.all()
        return super().formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)


class TagAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'status',)
    filter_horizontal = ('variety',)

    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "variety":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Variety.objects.filter(children__isnull=True)
        return super().formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Выдало вот такую ошибку 'ProductcopyAdmin' object has no attribute 'tag_set'

Comment: Проверьте еще раз, поправил

Comment: return super().formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)
^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function теперь такая ошибка и tag подчеркнут

Comment: Проверьте отступы

Comment: https://sun1-96.userapi.com/QWpEz78KN0Ysyb12DtER20RvRWCr-0Ec7He_bA/PzC5APC1-3I.jpg отступы нормальны

Comment: Проверьте ка еще раз. Проверить самому возможности нет, точно сказать не могу

Comment: спасибо. Можете еще с одним вопросом помочь https://sun9-39.userapi.com/dWjM5yxpa46FNYcg4rZjOVQrkertjJm9cmPZ6g/a6eLkDppuvk.jpg

Comment: Обновил ответ. Больше ничего не знаю :)

Answer (score 0):

решил с помощью smart-selects.
'''
variety = ChainedManyToManyField(
Variety,
verbose_name="вариации",
chained_field="tag",
chained_model_field="tag",
# auto_choose=True,
horizontal=True
)
'''